# For a vector space, are all of these subsets a vector space in and of themselves?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$.

Let $U \subset V$ such that $0_V \in U$, where $0_V$ is the zero vector of $V$, and $-u \in U \;\forall\;u \in U$, where $-u$ is the additive inverse of $u$.

Is $U$ together with the same operations as $V$ **always** a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$?

Or are there circumstances where this is not the case?

The reason I am asking this is because I have a list of questions that ask whether a particular subset is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. To me, it seems like they all are, because they all match the properties of $U$ above.

Comment: If $u,v\in U$, why should $u+v \in U$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the union of two lines?

Is that closed under the addition operation?

Comment: I don't see why it must be closed. I am asking if it is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, not a subspace.

Comment: Not with "the same operations as V"

Comment: Closedness [ if $a,b\in U,$ then $a+b\in U$] is one of the axioms of a vector space.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thank you all